# SAML2 Discovery Profile

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

Below Question related to SAML2 Discovery Profile

1. What the SAML2 Discovery Profile is all about?
2. What are the advantages of SAML2 Discovery Profile?

Answer (score 1):

The Discovery Profile can be used by an SP (Service Provider, i.e. application) to select which one of may possible IDPs (Identity Provider, i.e. login servers) to use to sign in the user.

When being a member of a federation with a dynamic list of identity providers the SP has to provide some means for the user to select the right IDP to use when logging in. Building that UI in each SP and maintaining a list of currently active IDPs is duplicate work. Thus a central *discovery service* is provided. The SP redirects the user to the discovery service, where the user can select IDP. The discovery service then redirects the user back.

There are also concepts in the profile for remembering a chosen IDP through cookies - including common domain cookies that might be directly readable by SPs.